# I have log4net setup just like in the examples, but it still doesn't work

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I have log4net setup just like in the examples.  In my config file, I have:

```
<configSections>
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
</configSections>
```

The appender configuration is setup just like it is shown on the log4net site for MS SQL Server surrounded by `<log4net>`.  http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html

In the AssemblyInfo.cs I have:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator]
```

Yet, nothing is showing up in my `[dbo].[Log]` table.

I have tried using the trace debugging text file, but no errors show up there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why no errors were showing up in the trace file is because no errors in log4net were happening.

The reason why there was nothing showing up in the `[dbo].[Log]` table was because the default config on the l4n site has `<bufferSize value="100" />`.  It is my understanding that this bufferSize would mean that l4n would wait until there are 100 messages queued up before writing them to the database.  So, to fix it for me, I just changed the value to "1".